# About VTN feature of OpenDaylight

Tags: linux, opendaylight, openflow

I evaluate OpenDaylight and I have a question.

I have practiced VTN document i.e https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/user-guide/virtual-tenant-network-(vtn).html . to construct a gateway (or router) feature with only OpenDaylight and OpenvSwitch .

And I have one question and my practice has stopped .

There is description of "90-vtn-neutron.xml" at the section "OpenDaylight Settings and Execution" of https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/user-guide/virtual-tenant-network-(vtn).html .

I have installed  distribution-karaf-0.5.0-Boron , but there is no "90-vtn-neutron.xml" , i.e,

`root@kaneko-PowerEdge-T130:/home/kaneko# ls distribution-karaf-0.5.0-Boron/etc/opendaylight/karaf/00-netty.xml   05-clustering.xml`                 42-openflowplugin-Li.xml   80-vtn.xml

`01-md-sal.xml  06-clustered-entity-ownership.xml  45-openflowjava-stats.xml`

In this connection, "feature:install odl-vtn-manager-neutron" has normal ended .

What shall I do?

Shall I not care this section?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation link you posted is for the Oxygen release so I'd suggest to install that version. The Boron release is old and no longer maintained/supported upstream.